# Is the amplitude of an EM wave the combination of the electric AND magnetic fields added together?

Tags: electromagnetism

For instance, to get the TOTAL energy of an EM wave(s) or intensity you square the amplitude.  But do you first add or combine the strengths of the e and m fields?

Comment: you cannot combine E and B because they have different dimensions and point in different directions.

Comment: they both contribute to the total energy which is not directionally dependent. And their vectors form the Poynting vector which is going to have a magnitude like any other vector.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two sources of Electric field, $E_1$, and $E_2$

Then $\vec{E_{tot}}=\vec{E_1}+\vec{E_2}.$

So the total intensity is
$$E^2_{tot}=(\vec{E_1}+\vec{E_2})^2=E^2_1+E_2^2+2\vec{E_1}\cdot\vec{E_2}$$

So the intensity of the sum of two electric fields is not the sum of their intensities individually.

The same thing applies to a magnetic field.

Now both the E field and the B field can carry energy. Not only is there the complexity of the above, summing the associated intensities has it's own complications.

Are you familiar with the Poyting Vector?

$$\vec{S}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}\vec{E}\times\vec{B}$$

It satisfies the energy conservation equation of electro magnetic waves.

$$\nabla\cdot \vec{S}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=0$$

$$u=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0E^2+\frac{1}{2\mu_0}B^2$$

$u$ is the energy desnity of the fields. The Poyting Vector indicates the direction of the flow of energy of the EM field.

So the energy density is a linear combination of the sum of their intensities, but neither exactly  the sum of their intensities nor the intensities of their sums.

Comment: I would lose the last section on adding electric and magnetic fields together as it's both confusing and physically meaningless.

Comment: the constants make it so you can add what is there, it's neither the electric nor magnetic field by itself. and you use those constants to get B in terms of E, thus getting rid of B in the equation.